# speech recognition in android not working

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, speech-to-text

I m trying to create an application in which when a call comes to the phone, call must automatically attend or end according to the user speech command. here i m giving what i tried, i m getting error in  startVoiceRecognitionActivity() method like Activity not found exception:no activity found to handle intent.

```
   public void startVoiceRecognitionActivity()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Voice recognition Demo...");
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        String spch = data.getStringExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);


        if (spch.contains("Yes"))    
         {
            enableSpeakerPhone(this);

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
            KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK);
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, event );
            this.sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);
         }
         else if(spch.contains("No"))
         {
            Intent buttonUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON); 
            buttonUp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
            this.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonUp, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
         }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

can anyone help me to find out the issue...

Comment: are you by any chance testing on an emulator ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared your activity correctly in manifest file?